# Ubuntu 11.10, Nvidia GeForce 8400 gs driver support?

Tags: nvidia

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 two weeks ago and I have been trying since then to install my graphic card but it does not seem to be working. help anyone?

Comment: ...and what exactly isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed the NVidia proprietary drivers? You can install the latest driver by going to "Additional Drivers" and selecting one from the list of available drivers.

Side note: A lot of details are missing from your post. If you like more help, please update your post with more details. I think this is your first post, welcome to Ask Ubuntu :) this place is awesome!

Answer (score 1):

My workstation uses the exact same card, I have LTS running on it with nvidia latest 295 drivers which I installed via x-swat ppa, it runs and installs fine here.